# setting bash editor as vscode throw error node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

I am trying to set up visual studio code as default editor on git bash. However, I keep facing the following issue.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Library\c\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:987:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:832:27)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I've tried to reinstall vscode, git and nodejs. But it doesn't help.

Also tried editing the env path to no avail.

The error seems to lie in the module path itself which resolves to duplicated "c\Users\username..."

Appreciate any help here. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I manage to dig deeper and found out that it is due to these particular lines of code that is causing the issue.

```
elif [ -x "$(command -v cygpath)" ]; then  <-- THIS LINE
    CLI=$(cygpath -m "$VSCODE_PATH/resources/app/out/cli.js")
```

They can be found in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.

Apparently, code is referencing to the cygpath that was installed by anaconda3 and hence ran the if statement. If I comment these 2 lines out to prevent cygpath from running, I am able to open vscode via bash with no issue. However, I don't think this is the long term solution.

Appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is also an issue in Windows when using Git bash. After installing Anaconda, I could no longer use the "code ." in the Git bash terminal. No issue when using cmd though.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue after running `conda init` as an administrator on my system. Following your advice, I commented the line:

```
CLI=$(cygpath -m "$VSCODE_PATH/resources/app/out/cli.js").
```

Then inserted this line to replace it

```
CLI="$VSCODE_PATH/resources/app/out/cli.js"
```

It is working fine now.

This is what my file looks like now.
[Changed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP3Vk.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.

Comment: This works, but can anyone explain why? Anaconda and VSCode are very commonly used together, they shouldn't conflict like this. Is there an issue submitted for this?